# How do you capture the localizer in an A320?

Tags: landing, airbus-a320, instrument-procedures, ils

I understand that pushing 'Approach' should do it (when in range), but it doesn't. There must be another step that I'm missing (the computer has been set up so it's not that).

What is the step-by-step procedure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. On the MCDU **F-PLN** page, select the arrival airport (LSK6L) and then select **ARRIVAL** (LSK1R). Then select the ILS approach you intend to fly. Make sure the ILS approach is now shown under APPR, e.g.:

   [image: MCDU ARRIVAL page]
2. Frequency tuning is automatic, there is no need to manually dial in the localizer frequency or select a course. You can however verify these on the **RAD NAV** page, e.g.:

   [image: MCDU RAD NAV page]
3. Select the **LS** push button on both EFIS controllers (CPT and F/O) and optionally also on the standby instrument. You should now see ILS indications on the PFD:

   [image: LS button and ILS indications]
4. Activate the **APPR** phase on the MCDU. This happens automatically when reaching the deceleration point (circled magenta D on the ND), but you can manually enable it via the MCDU **PERF** page using "ACTIVATE APPR PHASE" (and confirm):

   [image: MCDU PERF DES page]
5. Enable **APPR** mode on the FCU:

   [image: FCU]

   You can optionally enable the second autopilot at this stage as well. You should see both **LOC** and **G/S** in blue (armed) on the FMA now:

   [image: PFD with LOC G/S armed]
6. Now fly an intercept heading across the localizer. The **LOC** mode will become active automatically and the aircraft will establish itself on the localizer. Afterwards, the glideslope will be captured automatically (note that the other way round is often disabled by company policy).

---

All images from: [FlyByWire A320 Beginner's Guide](https://docs.flybywiresim.com/pilots-corner/beginner-guide/overview/)

Comment: What does the 2nd AP do?

Comment: @Cloud If you want to do a Cat II or III autoland, you need both autopilots to be engaged. Even if you don't plan on doing an autoland, it can be helpful to have both engaged during approach because if one fails, you will only down-grade to CAT1 SINGLE instead of a complete autopilot disengagement (which would typically require a go around on final approach).